# Should I put height and weight attribute on image tag even if they are not 100% right

Tags: html

I am developing a web application where use can upload pictures. I create thumbnails of various sizes. Lets say that one of the sizes is 240, 240 .

For this thumbnail when I render the image I want to put "height" and "width" attribute as it is recommended. However the image uploaded by user might be really tall and skinny. In that case the width will not be "240".

What is the recommended height and width attribute for this case. Or should I not worry about height and weight attribute for thumbnails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not put an incorrect `width` and `height` on an `img` element. What you *should* do, however, is output the correct size image when you're creating the thumbnail. For example, instead of scaling an image down from `500`x`200` to `240`x`96`, create a new, transparent image that is `240`x`240` and place the scaled image (`240`x`96`) in the middle of the transparent image. Then, you can specify the `width` and `height` on the `img`, and not incorrectly stretch any images.

Answer (score 0):

The height and width attributes tell the browser the dimensions of the space on the rendering canvas to use for the image.

If the actual image is not that size, it will be scaled to match.  If it is not the same aspect ratio, the image will be stretched or compressed as part of the scaling.

You should probably specify the actual dimensions.

What is probably appropriate is to scale the thumbnail so that the largest dimension is 240.  If the image isn't square, then the other dimension should scale by the same ratio.  For example, if the user uploads a 480x100 image, you would scale it to 240x50, preserving the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes aren't actually required, so if you don't know them, don't put them in.

Do you actually want the images to appear distorted? If not, you'll end up changing the height and width later anyway, so the attributes with dummy values wouldn't really serve any useful purpose. As I recall, they're recommended for performance reasons so the browser doesn't have to set the image dimensions later once it knows them.

Comment: It's highly recommended to set the `width` and `height` of `img` elements as not setting them will cause the page to reflow (other elements will move) when the images load (unless, of course, the containing element has no other children and has a set size). So not only is it for performance reasons, but the end user *notices* an improvement when image sizes are set specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, if you can be assured that ONE of the dimensions is fixed, then you should set that dimension.

If you are building a uniform grid that contains non-uniform content, you could set the height and width on the containing DIVs/table cells/what have you.